# I want to set up redirects in htaccess from one domain to another but I've gone wrong somewhere

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have a website, let's say `fruit.com`, and currently I have a bunch of redirects set up that work just fine, so for example `fruit.com/apples/mcintosh` will redirect to `fruit.com/apples.php?id=mcintosh`.

I also used to have some redirects set up to allow me to use a short URL, so `fru.it/mcintosh` would redirect to `fruit.com/apples.php?id=mcintosh`.

So far so good. A few years ago, though, my short domain lapsed and I didn't renew. Recently I've purchased it again and I'm interested in getting the same setup back.

Now, though, the redirects from the short domain to the main domain aren't working, although I've used exactly the same code, so I'm at a bit of a loss for what's going wrong.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.fru\.it$
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)$ "http\:\/\/www\.fruit\.com\/apples.php?id=$1" [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

> although I've used exactly the same code

But the code you've posted won't redirect the stated example URL `fru.it/mcintosh`, since the code matches digits only, not letters.

Try the following instead:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.fru\.it
RewriteRule ^(\w+)$ http://www.fruit.com/apples.php?id=$1 [R=301,L]
```

The `\w` shorthand character class matches upper and lowercase letters, numbers and underscore.

You don't need all the backslash-escapes in the *substitution* string.

Also bear in mind that the order of these directives can be important. This rule would likely need to go near the top of the `.htaccess` file to avoid conflicts.

Test first with a 302 (temporary) redirect to avoid potential caching issues. Clear your browser cache before testing.

---

*Aside:*

> `fruit.com/apples/mcintosh` will redirect to `fruit.com/apples.php?id=mcintosh`

It would seem to make more sense that this would be a (internal) "rewrite", not a (external) "redirect"? The shortcode would then redirect to `fruit.com/apples/mcintosh`, not `fruit.com/apples.php?id=mcintosh`?

Comment: Ah, yes, sorry, I changed the details instead of sharing the real domain, but in actual use, I'm using only numbers, no letters.

Backslashes removed, and I've moved this to before any other redirect in the .htaccess file. Tried with both 302 and 301. Still nothing sadly.